# Javacc How can i make a variable accessible to scanner and parser

Tags: java, javacc

Im trying to create a Map containing all function names. I can do this in the scanning phase or the parsing phase but can't seem to get the same variable to be accessible to both.

What I need is to have all the function names saved in a map before it begins parsing, as a function can be declared below the point where its called. So I need to check that that function exists.

I have tried using token mgr declarations which allows me to add the tokens to the map each time it is seen. But then I need the funcs variable to be seen by parser so it can check the function exists.

```
    TOKEN_MGR_DECLS : {
        public static Map funcs = new HashMap();
    }
    TOKEN : { 
       <FNAME: (["A"-"Z"])+ > { funcs.put(matchedToken.image, "..");}
    }
```

This is the closest I have got, I have tried a global variable in the .jj file, just below PARSER_BEGIN(..), and also declared it within the main function. Both of which lead to 'Symbol can't be found' error when trying to add function names to the map.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Keep in mind that scanning and parsing are done in the same pass.

Answer (score 1):

First I have to say that I recommend against having any variables shared between the parser and the lexer. This is because the lexer can be well ahead of the parser meaning that:

- If the variable is written by the lexer and read by the parser, the information might be out of date (i.e. overwritten) by the time the parser reads it.
- If the variable is written by the parser and read by the lexer, the information the lexer needs might not have been written by the parser when the lexer needs it.

That said.  If you need to do it.  Here is one way.  Declare your variable in the token manager like this

```
TOKEN_MGR_DECLS : {
    Map funcs = new HashMap();
}
```

Then, in the parser, you can access the variable as `token_source.funcs`.

If you use the `STATIC=true` option, then the variable should be `static`.

Answer (score 0):

To Make thinks clear you want to know the flow for the javacc parser.

Actual JavaCC Process starts with parser section, which invoke the TokenManager to return a token to process by calling getNextToken() method. Which intern call the character character stream (SimpleCharStream or JavaCharStream) to return character by character to the TokenManager.

```
   Parser
    /|\
     | getNextToken()
    \|/
TokenManager
    /|\
     | readChar()
    \|/
SimpleCharStream
```